# Language Specific Site

Tags: i18n-l10n

Is it possible to create a site that has multiple languages available to the user?

Preferably as similarly as possible to asp.net using .resx files (see here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/917414)

Is there any modules you have used that can provide this sort of functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [internationalization collection](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) as recommended by 7wonders is a good and useful set of modules, but you should first check the [Core locale](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/locale) module, as Core provides the basis of the functionality that you request.

Answer (score 4):

The [internationalization collection](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) will allow you to offer full language support for the user in the form of variables and all sorts so it is more feature full than the solution you linked.